# How to use @-webkit in style tag

Tags: css

This is a relatively simple question but i googled around with no luck. I'm trying to put the following CSS code into a style tag on my page. The "@" symbol is not being recognized in the style tag. It works in the CSS file just not the style tag, and for organizational/debugging purposes I would like it in the style tag now and not in the CSS. Any ideas?

```
 .spinnerClass {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    -webkit-animation: rotation .8s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotation .8s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: rotation .8s linear infinite;
    animation: rotation 0.8s linear infinite;
    border-left: 10px solid rgb(0,150,240);
    border-right: 10px solid rgb(0,150,240);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(0,150,240);
    border-top: 10px solid rgb(100,0,200);
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(200,100,250);
}
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @keyframes rotation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Comment: hmm well see updated description, that code is being recognized fine in the CSS file. This is CSS 3 rotation.

Comment: Which browser is this occuring in? All browsers?

Comment: Hi @timolawl thanks for getting back to me. I found the issue, answer is below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stated above says that using the "@" character in the style tag of the aspx page causes a compilation error and breaks the page.

Below is the code I was trying to put in the  tag.

```
<style>
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @keyframes rotation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
<style>
```

The page was throwing a compilation error because the "@" symbol is reserved for the Razor engine (used in asp .net MVC web projects). The solution is to escape the "@" character with another "@" character. So the code below is what worked.

```
<style>
    @@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @@-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
    @@keyframes rotation {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
<style>
```